# layout_gravity not centering my view vertically

Tags: android

I'm trying to center just one of my views in a relative layout. I'm using the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.21"
    android:id="@+id/atm_map_legend_view">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/atm_icon_legend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/help_icon"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/icon_legend_point"
        android:src="@drawable/blurb_point_down"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/atm_icon_legend"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This gets the following result:

[image: pic of icon uncentered]

As you can see, the `ImageButton` is not centering vertically. Using `android:gravity` works, but then it messes with the `ImageView` when that pops up (it causes it to move down, overlapping with the `ImageButton`.)

Any ideas as to why this isn't centering my `ImageButton`?

Comment: `layout_gravity` only works in a `FrameLayout` or other layouts which are based on `FrameLayout`, it doesn't work in a `RelativeLayout`. The `RelativeLayout` uses different attributes,  in this case you are looking for `layout_centerVertical` which expects a boolean `true` or `false` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`?

Like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.21"
    android:id="@+id/atm_map_legend_view">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/atm_icon_legend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]